# Is this mold or fungus from my Mykos (Mycorrhizae) powder? Also, my leaves have slight yellow spots on them?

Tags: plant-health, fungus, peppers, hydroponic, mold

These are 4 week old jalapenos. I am growing them in grow bags and I see white fuzz (not sure what it is) on most of the grow bags. Also noticing some spotting on the leaves. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I cant see anything on the leaves, could you post some photos of affected leaves please.

Answer (score 2):

The fuzz on the bag looks like fungus, probably because there is no air circulation between the bag and the bin.  Since it is not on the plants, I wouldn't worry about it.